# How can I loop objects and change values without errors in typescript?

Tags: typescript

When I used Typescript and I got the error below.

I just wanted to loop an object and change values inside them.

But Typescript gave me the error even though it actually worked very well.

How can I remove the error from typescript in this script?

```
const info = {
    id: "slkmd",
    password: "asdfasdf!",
    num: 1
}
const target = {
    id: "asdf",
    password: "asdf",
    num: 21
}
Object.keys(info).forEach(key => {
    info[key as keyof typeof info] = target[key as keyof typeof target]; // Error
    // Type 'string | number' is not assignable to type 'never'.
    // Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'never'
});

console.log(info);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here `keyof typeof info` is `"id" | "password" | "num"`. It's one of those values but typescript doesn't know which one.

So when you do:

```
info[key] = target[key]
```

It's like doing:

```
 info[key as "id" | "password" | "num"] = target[key as "id" | "password" | "num"]
```

See the problem? Typescript believes that, for example, it's possible for the first `key` to be `password` and the second `key` to `num`, which would be an invalid assignment. Typescript isn't quite smart enough to know that `key` must be the same member of that union in each place, it only sees the type in each spot and makes the (correct) type error.

---

To fix it, the function must become generic.

```
const keys = Object.keys(info) as Array<keyof typeof info>
keys.forEach(<K extends keyof typeof info>(key: K) => {
    info[key] = target[key];
});
```

Now the inner function has a generic parameter `K`, which will be one *specific* key of `info`, that is one *specific* member of that union.

The type of key in the function here is:

```
K extends "id" | "password" | "num"
```

Which means that it's a subtype of that union. And everywhere that type K is used will be the same subtype of that union for that invocation of the function.

And thus, the compiler's hunger is sated.

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.5.4#code/MYewdgzgLgBAlmAZiGBeGBvAUDX8AmAXDAEQQA2A1gLb4kA0OeADgIYQQDuIATkae3yJBiAIQMmuMAFdqxAIxYAvllCRYUVjwDmAU1jpseAsRIiJxth259T5xsZlyYAJkUrV4aDEq6AnhBoMADyAEYAVrrAUAB0vgEAFAjIAJQw7DAAgjw8rH4APPEgiDBQfsy6xfBIIAB8WPEQMcg8AKKswAAWCfkA0jC6AB5QumD4gUUlZRVVyXUJ8cS9aai1mJLVyADa8QC6QZo6+jv+uwDcyikXnpAg5Lox5CDaSTVXQA)